# Can Service Account impersonation be done using Keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can we use the Service Account Key to impersonate a Service Account?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. What problem are you having?

Comment: No problems as of now, I am just trying to understand about Service Account impersonation. Thank you!

Comment: For a better security, try to find a way to avoid the use of service account key file. Most of the use case are compliant without.

Comment: Hello @Sabari. Hope the provided answer is helpful to proceed with Service Account impersonation. Can you upvote or accept if existing answer helps

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the comment was helpful!